# mainframe copybook with redefines clause to load data in oracle external table

Tags: oracle, external, clause, copybook

I have redefines clause in a copybook that I have to load into oracle external table using the file sent over. Below is the copybook information. Incoming file is in positional format Should I assume in the data record in file, first 8 characters is for alphanumeric, and next 8 characters is for numeric. I just need to know if I should account for 16 characters total for this, because there are other fields in the copybook before and after this field.

e.g.

ENROLLMENT-DT  PIC X(08).
ENROLLMENT-DT-N
    REDEFINES
    ENROLLMENT-DT PIC 9(08

Answer (score 0):

Allow 8 bytes in total for the 2 fields. For this example, redefines signifies the 2 fields occupy the same position in the record. The copybook lets you look at the field as either a String field or a Text field

Another example of redefines is

```
 03  Birth-Date         pic 9(8).
 03  redefines Birth-Date.
     05 Birth-year      pic 9(4)
     05 Birth-Month     pic 99.
     05 Birth-Day       pic 99.
```

This allows you to access date in both YYYYMMDD format + the individual Year/Month/Day fields

```
 Move 20180612          to Birth-Date
```

then

```
 Birth-year = 2018
 Birth-Month = 06
 Birth-Day = 12
```

Similarly if you do

```
 Move 2020         to Birth-year
 Move 02           to Birth-Month 
 Move 21           to Birth-Day
```

then Birth-Date=20200221

---

If the file is coming from an **IBM Mainframe**,  the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) can display the position/length of a Cobol Copybook fields

In RecordEditor option **Utilities >>> Display Cobol Copybook**
a Cobol copybook is displayed like:

[image: Cobol Copybook]

finally the cb2xml will convert a Mainframe Cobol copybook to xml (with the position and lengths in the Xml).